# How to fix the datagridview to show the double valeues properly?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, double

So I live in Hungary and I am making a windows form application in c# and I am using a double value in my datagridview and to me it shows perfectly.(ex. 3,4). But i am making this program to an other country, Spain. And to my friend in Spain the comma does not show up in the datagridview. So for him it shows 34.

Does anyone have an idea what should I include to my code to show commas in "every country"?

Expected output of 3,4 to be 3,4, but the actual output is 34. (in spain)

```
if (File.Exists("files/returned.txt"))
        {
            string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines("files/returned.txt");
            int n = int.Parse(allLines[0]);
            int dgvCount = 0;
            dgv2.RowCount = 0;
            dgv2.RowCount = n;

            for(int i = 1;i<n+1;i++)
            {
                string[] splitt = allLines[i].Split('\t');
                DateTime a = DateTime.Parse(dt_from.Value.ToShortDateString());
                DateTime b = DateTime.Parse(dt_to.Value.ToShortDateString());

                DateTime c = DateTime.Parse(splitt[2]);

                if(tb_returned_sn.Text != "")
                {
                    if (splitt[1].StartsWith(tb_returned_sn.Text) && DateTime.Compare(a, c) <= 0 && DateTime.Compare(b, c) >= 0)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
                        {
                            dgv2.Rows[dgvCount].Cells[j].Value = splitt[j];
                        }
                        dgvCount++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(DateTime.Compare(a, c) <= 0 && DateTime.Compare(b, c) >= 0)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
                        {
                            dgv2.Rows[dgvCount].Cells[j].Value = splitt[j];
                        }
                        dgvCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
            dgv2.RowCount = dgvCount;
            if(dgvCount == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NOT FOUND");
                bt_excel.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                bt_excel.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The equipments' database does not exist!");
        }
        tb_returned_sn.Focus();
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code!

Comment: Edited, the double value is in a file, so i have to read them. But for me it shows perfectly, but in Spain it misses the commas, so thats why im so confused because I tried it in many computers and in Hungary it was working well...

Comment: Sounds like a localization issue. Are the text files the same? What do they contain? Commas or decimal points? Both Hungary and Spain should use the decimal comma but maybe one of the machines is set up differently..

Comment: I am using commas, because C# allows commas to double variables.

Comment: I have asked 3 questions. This answers none. Double is a number type and contains no commas or points. Only the output strings do. Parsing input strings depends on the culture the application assumes.

Answer (score 1):

All simple types with `Parse` and `ToString` methods have overloads that accept an `IFormatProvider` argument. Here you can use a `CultureInfo` instance (or `NumberFormatInfo`/`DateTimeFormatInfo`), which provides information about such culture-specific information as decimal sign and thousands separator.

The default `int.Parse`, `DateTime.ToString`, etc. overloads use the `Thread.CurrentCulture` to determine this information, which can be different on different work stations depending on regional settings.

**Hence the rules of thumb:**

1. When *storing* floating point numbers or date-time values as string in a database (or in text files as in your case) *do always use a specific culture* (preferably the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`) so when your 'database' is parsed on different computers with different regional settings you will always get consistent results. For example:

```cs
// of course, it must be also stored with invariant culture
int n = int.Parse(allLines[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

2. For *displaying* the values in a UI you can use the current regional settings. But instead of using the default `ToString` overloads it is still preferred to specify the culture to make the intention clear. For example:

```cs
myDateTime.ToString("d", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); // d for short date format
```

**As for the 3,4 vs 34:**

Though both Hungarian and Spanish (at least in Spain) uses comma as decimal sign, the regional settings must be something different (English?) on the computer, which parses 3,4 as 34 because with English settings the comma is interpreted as thousands separator.